# SeLinux revert semanage command for mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, installation

I am using Centos Version 7 and installed mysql using yum install. I then tried to change the location of mysql using the instructions from the following page: [instructions](http://crashmag.net/change-the-default-mysql-data-directory-with-selinux-enabled)

I now want to revert these changes. In order to do this, i changed the values in my.cnf back to `/var/lib/mysql` but I am wondering how I can revert the semanage and restorecon commands that I ran?

Basically I ran:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/srv/mysql(/.*)?"
```

and then:

```
restorecon -Rv /srv/mysql
```

Do I simply rerun these commands but use `/var/lib/mysql(/.*?)` as the argument to the semanage command?